# Assign '\' to char

Tags: c++, char, assign, backslash

How do I assign the value of '\' to a character variable?

C++ doesn't recognize the backslash as a character and thinks there should be a 't' or 'n' or something afterwards.

How can the `\` be assigned to a `char` variable?

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape it properly: `'\\'`

Comment: While that is technically valid, you maybe should give some more explanations what's actually _special_ with \.

Answer (score 4):

The backslash character is used as 'escape' sign for characters like `'\"'` or `'\''` to give them a special meaning for their appearance in literals instead of closing the literal.

There's also a number of escaped character values with more *special meanings* like e.g. `'\n'`, that expands to a new line in output.

To give the *special meaning* for the `\` character, it must be escaped itself:

```
char c = '\\';
       // ^
```

Comment: Good answer. I've deleted my comments.